# Drawbacks of CSS3 animation of SVG objects?

Tags: performance, css, svg, css-animations

So I'm just getting into SVG and learning how it works. At the moment I am creating a project that involves rotating several SVG `<circle>`s at different speeds, thus learning how `animateTransform` works.

However, I found out that one can use CSS3 animations (which I am much more familiar with) on SVG objects. I realize that `animateTransform` can do more complex animations, but I'm talking in terms of a simple animation that both options have the capability of completing.

**What are the drawbacks** (if any) **of CSS3 animations used on SVG objects when compared to `animateTransform`?** Does `animateTransform` perform better?

Comment: I found some useful information (and an awesome next-gen js animation platform) in the start of [this SlideDeck presentation](http://www.slideshare.net/brianskold/serious-animation-an-introduction-to-web-animations)

Answer (score 3):

No IE support for <animate… you have to use a polyfill library like fakeSMIL - which is not the end of the world. Also css3 transforms are GPU accelerated on iOS mobile and chrome for mobile (for the most part) so they tend to be smoother.